# Like button on every single row of listview

Tags: android, listview, row, instagram

Im  trying to implement instagram like listview , in each row there is like button and also comment box. the question is how can i achieve similar function in listview which means each row is specific and its not repeating for other rows , what i tries is , when a user clicks on button after some item , all other items are clicked! means the clicked item is repeating and its obvious i don't want this! how can i achieve instagram like row

```
        @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    viewHolder mHolder;
    if(convertView==null){
        mHolder = new viewHolder();
        convertView = mInflator.inflate(R.layout.row_all_artist, parent, false);
        mHolder.mArtistName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.artist_name);
        mHolder.mFollowers = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.artist_followers);
        mHolder.mFollow = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.artist_follow);
        AppLogic.ChangeTextViewFont(mContext, mHolder.mArtistName);
        convertView.setTag(mHolder);

    } else{
        mHolder = (viewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    mHolder.mArtistName.setText(mItems.get(position).getArtistFullName());
    mHolder.mFollowers.setText(mItems.get(position).getArtistFollowers());
    mHolder.mFollow.setTag(R.id.artist_follow,mItems.get(position).getArtistID());
    mHolder.mFollow.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) mContext);

    return convertView;
}
```

**EDIT**

my question is not about touching items or setting unlike listener or like this! the problem is when i click the button i change its background color , but this color is repeating on every 10 item on the list! there is a related question to me here : [ListView repeated CheckBox behavior every 10th item erratically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26080073/listview-repeated-checkbox-behavior-every-10th-item-erratically)

```
public void onClick(final View v) {

    if (!AppLogic.isLoggined(mShared)) {
        AppLogic.ToastMaker(getApplicationContext(),
                getResources().getString(R.string.msg_loginError));
        startActivity(new Intent(FirstTimePage.this, Register.class)
                .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));

    } else {

        AppLogic.doFollow(FirstTimePage.this, v, mShared);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can get help here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17267859/how-to-obtain-the-checked-rows-in-a-custom-view-list/17268392#17268392

Comment: In in the moment you touch one all backgrounds does change?

Answer (score 1):

Prevent getting focus by the button.

Add this to the top element in your *row_all_artist.xml* custom view

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

Comment: the problem is not the buttons are not clickable! my problem is when i click a button i change its background , but its repeating on every 10 item on listview , like recycle

Answer (score 0):

Create a new OnClickListener for every row, or check the View given in the argument at your current listener.

Comment: my answer still apply, wheres your onClick implementation from mContext?

Comment: please consider , there is no problem on item clicking , i put the o'clock method @Marcos

Answer (score 0):

You are setting your mContext as the `OnClickListener`

```
mHolder.mFollow.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) mContext);
```

You should just implement the `ListView` method `setOnItemClickListener` and then check for the position of the item that was clicked. `Tag`s are also very helpful here.

Example: [Adding an onclicklistener to listview (android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9097723/adding-an-onclicklistener-to-listview-android)

Comment: problem is not on setting onclick listener , please read my edited question